# Create custom HTML page as administrator menu in Joomla 3.7

Tags: administrator, custom-component, custom-module, joomla-3.7

As we know Joomla 3.7 permits to create custom administrator menus, but is it somehow possibile to create "Custom HTML" administrator single item menu? Something like creating single article menu on front-end without a WYSWIG editor. This combined with a plugin like "Sourcerer" that permits to put some PHP code, or a custom module, would give an amazing opportunity to create some simple, custom components. I aspected to be able to do that in Joomla 3.7, but haven't found anything. Is it somehow possibile? If not, have anyone thought about it? And if yes, then there is no option to do that?

Comment: I would have security concerns when joomla implement this kind of feature from core. Why not writing a component, where you implement your "nice" feature? It is not a good idea to bypass Joomla's legally-secure API. Think about it.

Comment: Yes it's not the best idea, fear of many developers abusing it, but it would give an easy way to implement some easy stuff. For me we could give it a try, since making components for something easy is little to hard and time consuming.